# How to app stylings to the calendar in DatePicker component MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a DatePicker component from Mui and I am trying to style the Calendar component by adding `position:abusolte`, `letf` and 'top' property.

My goal is to align the right side of the `TextField` component and the calendar.

This is the current apprearance...

[image]

Here is what I want to ....

[image]

How can I add stylings to the calendar?

Here is the [demo code](https://codesandbox.io/s/e2ciyl?file=/demo.js:455-668)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';

export default function BasicDatePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker
        label="Basic example"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

#### Attempts

1, I added `PopperProps` prop but that didn't work...

```
      <DatePicker
        label="Basic example"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
PopperProps={{
  sx: {'&.MuiPickersPopper-root': {position: 'absolute', top:'4px', left:'-23px'}},
}}
      />
```

2,Using styled-component

```
export const DatePicker = styled(DesktopDatePicker)`
  & .MuiPickersPopper-paper {
    position: absolute;
    left: -23px;
    top: 4px;
  }
`;
```

3, Added  that contains `TextField`

```
  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "100px" }}>
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <DatePickerStyled
          label="Basic example"
          value={value}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "flex-end"
              }}
            >
              <TextField {...params} />
            </div>
          )}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

4. Add `sx` prop in `TextField`

```
  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "100px" }}>
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <DatePickerStyled
          label="Basic example"
          value={value}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <div>
              <TextField
                {...params}
                sx={{
                  display: "flex",
                  justifyContent: "flex-end"
                }}
              />
            </div>
          )}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to a working solution. You have to target the `popper` slot component and style it that way. The docs are rather roundabout on explaining this and took me a while to figure out. Try this:

```
<DatePicker
  label="Basic example"
  value={value}
  onChange={(newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
  slotProps={{
    popper: {
      placement: "bottom-end"
    }
  }}
  sx={{
    width: "400px"
  }}
/>
```

You can also add an `sx` key to the `popper` object above if you want custom styling. The `placement` key should accomplish what you want though.

## Update

## =========

Here is a solution that moves the entire input to the right based on our comments below. Just nest the `DatePicker` inside of an MUI `Box` and justify content to flex-end:

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { AdapterDateFns } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";

export default function BasicDatePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "flex-end"
        }}
      >
        <DatePicker
          label="Basic example"
          value={value}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
          slotProps={{
            popper: {
              placement: "bottom-end"
            }
          }}
          sx={
            {
              // width: "400px"
            }
          }
        />
      </Box>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, I still see the same original styling.

Comment: When I use the google developer tool to see elements, there is `data-popper-placement` in the div tag for the calendar dialog. So I changed that value to `bottom-end` from `bottom`. But this didn't do anything. I also tried `top-right`, `top-left` etc

Comment: I tried the above code on the codepen that you linked. The width of your datepicker is less than the width of the popper which makes it look left aligned. I will edit the above code to set the width and you should be able to see the results

Comment: Try the edit I just made

Comment: Oh does the `TextField` need to be wider than the calendar dialog? In my case the width of the text input needs to be smaller than the calendar dialog.

Comment: I'm not sure about your exact scenario. All I have to go off of is the codepen you linked. In the codepen, the datepicker is left aligned in the browser and it's width is less than the calendar popper. Because of this, the popper will look left aligned even though it is trying to be right aligned. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that totally makes sense. and what I want to do here is the text input width needs to be `250px`, not `400px`. Could I still align both to the right side? Thank you very much!

Comment: The easiest way to align right is to place your textfield inside of a div and just align right inside the div. I have to work now but can help more later today is that still does not make sense

Comment: I added attempt #3 which is wrapping the `TextField` with a div tag that has `display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end'` but that also seems not working. I appreciate you if you could help me with this. Thank you!